# SharePoint 2013 APP Deployment Error: on-Premise hosted APP

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem

Today I have start working on SharePoint Hosted APP.

I have done with prerequisite [Setting up on-premises environment for app development](https://dev.office.com/hands-on-labs/1539)

After That I have created New Project.

When first time I have click on F5 button, it shows error below

```
Error   1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action.
```

Then one more time I have click on F5 button, this time it shows different error

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID
```

[image]

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Error 1:

Error says you can not use **System Account** for app deployment. use other account for app deployment. Or you can change the service account from Central Admin for this web application and try to deploy using same login account.

Reference:

- [Error occured in deployment step 'install app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action. Deploying App - On-Premises Farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68419/error-occured-in-deployment-step-install-app-for-sharepoint-the-system-accoun)
- [Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80812/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-uninstall-app-for-sharepoint-the-system-acc)

### For Error 2:

This type of error can occur when Uninstall is not done properly. Delete the app from **Site Contents** and **Recycle bin** completely.

Please **change the product id** from the `appmanifest.xml` file. It's random GUID. Generate new GUID and change it in appmanifest file. After that try to deploy your app. If issue persists, then also change version number along with GUID in appmanifest file.

Reference:

- http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/sharepoint-2013-apps-the-provided-app-differs-from-another-app-with-the-same-version-and-product-id/

Hope this will help you!